# Sort array of dictionaries by date key

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `[[Date:[Double]]]` which I would like to sort by nearest to farthest date based on the element's key, which is a date.

What is the most efficient way to do this using Swift? I have done this before using NSSortDescriptor but this was when sorting using a key/value pair. I have not sorted by the actual key itself before.

Example data:

```
[[2020-12-18 06:00:00 +0000: [475.4]], [2020-11-06 06:00:00 +0000: [427.475, 449.22]], [2020-11-06 00:09:33 +0000: [435.26, 441.605]]]
```

Comment: So your input is an array of multiple dictionaries, each of which has a single element? Why not put them all in one dictionary?

Comment: Your first step should be to abandon this data model. This should a struct with a `data` property and a `values` property.

Comment: You have an array of single-element dictionaries? I agree with Matt. Convert it to an array of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt suggests, make your model like this:

```
struct DateStruct {
   let date: Date
   let values: [Double]
}

var dateStructsArray: [DateStruct] = []
//Populate your array in whatever way makes sense
```

Then sorting it is as simple as using a single call to `sorted()`

Your code might look like this:

```
let sortedDateStructs = dateStructsArray.sorted { $0.date < $1.date }
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the direction. I also figured out the sorted predicate but you might want to add it to your answer as that is really what answers the question, for completeness to help other users on the site.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a sample call to `sorted()`.

Answer (score -1):

As Duncan Suggests:
first:Parsing data what you want,
second:set data to dateStruct for a array,you can use the array to do something.